# Get unique rows from a Scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with sparse matrices in python, I wonder if there is an efficient way to remove duplicate rows in a sparse matrix, and have only the unique rows remain.

I did not find a function associated with it and not sure how to do it without converting the sparse matrix to dense and use numpy.unique.

Comment: There's nothing in the `scipy` for that. `np.unique` with the new `axis` parameter is probably the best route.  If you have to stick with `sparse` I'd suggest looking at the `lil` format and its 'raw' rows and data attributes.

Answer (score 7):

There is no quick way to do it, so I had to write a function. It returns a sparse matrix with the unique rows (axis=0) or columns (axis=1) of an input sparse matrix.
Note that the unique rows or columns of the returned matrix are not lexicographical sorted (as is the case with the `np.unique`).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

def sp_unique(sp_matrix, axis=0):
    ''' Returns a sparse matrix with the unique rows (axis=0)
    or columns (axis=1) of an input sparse matrix sp_matrix'''
    if axis == 1:
        sp_matrix = sp_matrix.T

    old_format = sp_matrix.getformat()
    dt = np.dtype(sp_matrix)
    ncols = sp_matrix.shape[1]

    if old_format != 'lil':
        sp_matrix = sp_matrix.tolil()

    _, ind = np.unique(sp_matrix.data + sp_matrix.rows, return_index=True)
    rows = sp_matrix.rows[ind]
    data = sp_matrix.data[ind]
    nrows_uniq = data.shape[0]

    sp_matrix = sp.lil_matrix((nrows_uniq, ncols), dtype=dt)  #  or sp_matrix.resize(nrows_uniq, ncols)
    sp_matrix.data = data
    sp_matrix.rows = rows

    ret = sp_matrix.asformat(old_format)
    if axis == 1:
        ret = ret.T        
    return ret


def lexsort_row(A):
    ''' numpy lexsort of the rows, not used in sp_unique'''
    return A[np.lexsort(A.T[::-1])]

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # Test
    # Create a large sparse matrix with elements in [0, 10]
    A = 10*sp.random(10000, 3, 0.5, format='csr')
    A = np.ceil(A).astype(int)

    # unique rows
    A_uniq = sp_unique(A, axis=0).toarray()
    A_uniq = lexsort_row(A_uniq)
    A_uniq_numpy = np.unique(A.toarray(), axis=0)
    assert (A_uniq == A_uniq_numpy).all()

    # unique columns
    A_uniq = sp_unique(A, axis=1).toarray()
    A_uniq = lexsort_row(A_uniq.T).T
    A_uniq_numpy = np.unique(A.toarray(), axis=1)
    assert (A_uniq == A_uniq_numpy).all()
```

Comment: Excellente réponse avec un code de qualité. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

One could also use slicing

```
def remove_duplicate_rows(data):
    unique_row_indices, unique_columns = [], []
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(data):
        indices = row.indices.tolist()
        if indices not in unique_columns:
            unique_columns.append(indices)
            unique_row_indices.append(row_idx)
    return data[unique_row_indices]
```

I found this especially helpful when I was in a supervised machine-learning setting. There, the input to my function was data and labels. With this approach, I could easily return

```
labels[unique_row_indices]
```

aswell to make sure data and labels are on-par after this clean-up.

Comment: Note that this solution does not work with `lil_matrix` format; `csr_matrix` worked for me.

Comment: Also, this does not only remove duplicate rows, but also **all rows with duplicate column indices**. E.g. it will remove the second row of `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[1,1],[2,2]]))`.