# Cluster/Group continuous entries in a dataframe by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

#### Question

Suppose I have k scalar columns, and I'd like to group entries if they're within a certain distance of one another along each column.

Suppose for simpicity k is 2 and they're my only columns.

```
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(sorted(choices(range(0,10), k=20)), choices(range(20,29), k=20))), columns=['a','b'])
```

yields

```
[(1, 27),
 (1, 27),
 (1, 21),
 (2, 23),
 (3, 25),
 (4, 23),
 (4, 28),
 (4, 27),
 (4, 22),
 (4, 24),
 (5, 26),
 (6, 21),
 (7, 26),
 (7, 20),
 (8, 24),
 (8, 25),
 (8, 23),
 (9, 20),
 (9, 28),
 (9, 21)]
```

I want groupings such that groups include entries in column `a` which are at most `m` apart AND column `b` which are at most `n` apart. if `m` = `n` = 1, then the clustering would be:

```
(1, 27), (1, 27)
(1, 21)
(2, 23)
(3, 25), (4, 23), (4, 22), (4, 24)
(4, 28), (4, 27), (5, 26)
(6, 21), (7, 20)
(7, 26), (8, 24), (8, 25), (8, 23)
(9, 20), (9, 21)
(9, 28),
```

#### Notes

One way of accomplishing this would be with [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), but that isn't a good solution because:

- I have a lot of data -- don't want to do squared operations.
- the data is already sorted, and m, n are small relative to the ranges of the columns
- m =/= n (not always) otherwise manhattan distance threshold of m+n would work

I believe this might have been a very related question, but it doesn't have a general answer:

- [Group by continuous indexes in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675262/group-by-continuous-indexes-in-pandas-dataframe)

Sketch of an approach which might get you towards the answer:

```
a, b, c, d, e = tee(range(10), 5)
next(b, None)
next(c, None);next(c, None)
next(d, None);next(d, None);next(d, None)
next(e, None);next(e, None);next(e, None);next(e, None)
list(zip(a, b, c, d, e))

[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
 (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(3, 25)` be together with `(4, 23), (4, 22), (4, 24)` in your example?

Comment: @AndreasK. I am confused with that too. It seems the order of observation matters. For example, suppose the `next `sample of `(3,25)` is `(4,23)`, because `4-3 =1,23-25 = -2` so (4,23) is seperated with (3,25). But this does not explain why (3,25) and (4,24) are not in the same group...

Comment: `pdist` doesn't need to use squared operations.  With `metric = 'cityblock'` (Manhattan Distance) you'll be pretty close to what you want.

Comment: @AndreasK you're right, sorry about this, I've fixed the example.

Comment: @DanielF could you point me to some literature how pdist gets the speedup with cityblock?

Comment: Actually, you don't want `'cityblock'`, you want `'chebyshev'`.  and `pdist` is faster becasue of `c`-compiled operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we do `pdist` with `metric = 'chebyshev'`

```
test = np.array([(1, 27),
 (1, 27),
 (1, 21),
 (2, 23),
 (3, 25),
 (4, 23),
 (4, 28),
 (4, 27),
 (4, 22),
 (4, 24),
 (5, 26),
 (6, 21),
 (7, 26),
 (7, 20),
 (8, 24),
 (8, 25),
 (8, 23),
 (9, 20),
 (9, 28),
 (9, 21)])

from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
c_mat = squareform(pdist(test, metric = 'chebyshev')) <= 1
```

now `c_mat` is basically a graph of nodes that are connected if they are <1 apart in every direction

To find the full unconnected graphs, there is probably a fast operation you can do in `networx`, but I'll just to it the slightly harder way in `numpy` since I don't know what graph theory keywords to look for there.

```
out = np.ones((c_mat.shape[0], 2))
while out.sum(0).max() >1:
    c_mat = c_mat @ c_mat
    out = np.unique(c_mat, axis = 0)
```

Now `c_mat` is `True` if there is any chain that connects two rows, and `out` is the boolean indices of all the separate groups.  Now to return the result:

```
for mask in list(out):
    print(np.unique(test[mask], axis = 0))

[[ 9 28]]
[[ 9 20]
 [ 9 21]]
[[ 7 26]
 [ 8 23]
 [ 8 24]
 [ 8 25]]
[[ 6 21]
 [ 7 20]]
[[ 4 27]
 [ 4 28]
 [ 5 26]]
[[ 3 25]
 [ 4 22]
 [ 4 23]
 [ 4 24]]
[[ 2 23]]
[[ 1 21]]
[[ 1 27]]
```

You can also use these boolean indices to access the rows of data in your original `DataFrame`

**EDIT 1:**

Now, we can speed this up a lot using the fact that the inputs are semi-sorted.  But to do so we need `numba`

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def find_connected(data, dist = 1):
    i = list(range(data.shape[0]))
    j = list(range(data.shape[0]))
    l = data.shape[0]
    for x in range(1, l):
        for y in range(x, l):
            v = np.abs(data[x] - data[y])
            if v.max() <= dist:
                i += [x, y]
                j += [y, x]
            if v.min() > dist:
                break
    d = [1] * len(i)
    return (d, (i, j))
```

now we need to load that into a sparse matrix

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

c_mat =  csr_matrix(find_connected(test), dtype = bool)
```

`csr` does dot products much faster, so `c_mat = c_mat @ c_mat` works, but the stopping criteria breaks.  You can either use Anreas K.'s excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46126840/get-unique-rows-from-a-scipy-sparse-matrix), or just do `out = np.unique(c_mat.todense(), axis = 0)`.

**EDIT 2:**

Couldn't get this out of my head till I solved it without making a dense matrix.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.njit
def find_connected_semisort(data, dist = 1):
    l = data.shape[0]
    out = []
    for x in range(l):
        for y in range(x, l):
            v = np.abs(data[x] - data[y])
            if v.max() <= dist:
                out.append(set([x, y]))
            if v.min() > dist:
                break
    outlen = len(out)
    for x in range(outlen):
        for y in range(x + 1, outlen):
            if len(out[x] & out[y]) > 0:
                out[y] |= out[x]
                out[x].clear()
    return [list(i) for i in out if len(i) > 0]

[np.unique(test[i], axis = 0).squeeze() for i in find_connected_semisort(test)]
Out[]: 
[array([ 1, 27]), array([ 1, 21]), array([ 2, 23]), array([[ 3, 25],
    [ 4, 22],
    [ 4, 23],
    [ 4, 24]]), array([[ 4, 27],
    [ 4, 28],
    [ 5, 26]]), array([[ 6, 21],
    [ 7, 20]]), array([[ 7, 26],
    [ 8, 23],
    [ 8, 24],
    [ 8, 25]]), array([ 9, 28]), array([[ 9, 20],
    [ 9, 21]])]
```

There's probably some way to do it without two loops but I couldn't grok it.

Comment: Nice solution! +1. However what if m =/= n ? I think you could do something like `c_mat = squareform((pdist(test[:,0][:, None], 'cityblock') <= m) & (pdist(test[:,1][:, None], 'cityblock') <= n))` and `np.fill_diagonal(c_mat, True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question reminds me `lag` operation and `cumsum`. Here is a pandas answer. If your data is huge, I think use python `list` and `tuple` is fine, default modules must have functions to complete our mission.

## Step1: get the data

```
# generate data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import choices,seed
seed(1245)
data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(sorted(choices(range(0,10), k=20,)), choices(range(20,29), k=20))), columns=['a','b'])
```

## Step 2: lag with 1 length

```
# lag opertion
data_shift = data.shift(1,fill_value = -999)
data_shift.columns = ["a_last","b_last"]

# conbine them together to apply. If your data is huge, just call function on these 2 pieces of data
data_flat = pd.concat([data,data_shift],axis = 1)
data_flat.head()
```

Out:

```
   a   b  a_last  b_last
0  1  26    -999    -999
1  1  27       1      26
2  1  28       1      27
3  2  22       1      28
4  2  24       2      22
```

## Step 3: define custum functions,and then group your observations

```
# define your function with args m,n
def your_func(x,m,n):
    cond1 = (abs(x.a - x.a_last) <= m)
    cond2 = (abs(x.b - x.b_last) <= n)
    if cond1 & cond2:
        return 0
    else: 
        return 1
# calculate per row and get the group_id of samples
groups = data_flat.apply(your_func,axis = 1,m=1,n=1).cumsum()
# get the result
data.groupby(groups).apply(lambda x:list(map(tuple,x.values)))
```

Out:

```
1     [(1, 26), (1, 27), (1, 28)]
2                       [(2, 22)]
3                       [(2, 24)]
4                       [(3, 20)]
5                       [(3, 26)]
6              [(4, 21), (4, 20)]
7                       [(5, 28)]
8              [(5, 26), (5, 26)]
9                       [(6, 28)]
10                      [(6, 24)]
11                      [(6, 28)]
12                      [(7, 23)]
13                      [(7, 26)]
14             [(8, 28), (8, 28)]
15                      [(9, 26)]
dtype: object
```

Comment: It looks like in your output, there are 2 copies of (6, 28) in different output lists?

Comment: when we generate data，there could have same values in different location. I did not figure out whether the order of observation matters in your post